# Are ambiguous robot legs valid?

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, guice, robot-legs-problem

In the [Guice FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions), they talk about differentiating multiple instances with annotations (kind of).

My question: Can I bind a Impl to an Interface without an annotation, and bind another Impl to that same Interface *with* an annotation?  Basically my first impl is going to act as a container for the others.

```
bind(SecurityAuthorizer.class).to(CompositeSecurityAuthorizer.class);
bind(SecurityAuthorizer.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named(ComponentAuthorizer.class.getSimpleName()))
    .to(ComponentAuthorizer.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Bonus question, is our usage of Names.named(..) considered bad form?  Just trying to avoid creating a ton of annotation classes, yet wanted the benefits of being able to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that should just work. You might want to also look at [Multibindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings), which is designed for scenarios like this one. The composite implementation would inject the set of interfaces:

```
public class CompositeSecurityAuthorizer {
    @Inject 
    CompositeSecurityAuthorizer(Set<SecurityAuthorizer> authorizers) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a Gin module, so Multibindings aren't supported yet. http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=111